# fsockopen fails to connect with SSL (HTTPS) url. while using Gallery 3 for image upload

Tags: php, ssl, https, fsockopen

I'm using Gallery 3 for image upload. 
When I use https://domain the upload works fine. But as I use https://domain Gallery3 is not able to make a connection.

```
Errors : **fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in fileName** 

 **fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in finleName**

**fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://domain:443 (Unknown error) in /**
```

Below are the observations:

1. The URL to connect becomes ssl://domain having port 443
2. fsockopen fails to make a connects and throws error.

What is going wrong ? I have a valid https certificate on my server and also openssl is installed.

Anything else required ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.6+ [updated the default ciphers](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php) based on the [Mozilla cipher recommendations](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_Ciphersuite). There is more detail about what ciphers are used in the [RFC for improving tls defaults](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/improved-tls-defaults). Overall this change removed support for Anonymous Diffie-Hellman and RC4, it's likely your server still uses RC4.

There are two options:

1. Update the ciphers your server is using based on the Mozilla ciper recommendations
2. Update the gallery3 code to use RC4, since it hasn't been updated since 2013 you can probably do this option without too much concern

For option 2 it looks like the call is done in *gallery3/modules/gallery/helpers/MY_remote.php* on line 73/74:

```
$handle = fsockopen(
  $url_components['fsockhost'], $url_components['port'], $errno, $errstr, 5);
```

You can change this to use [`stream_socket_client`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) which is compatible with `fsockopen`:

```
$context = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
    'ciphers' => 'RC4-MD5'
]]);
$timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');

$handle = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $url_components['fsockhost'] . ':' . $url_components['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```